# Where do Xcode projects get created? And can I change default location of a project?

Tags: xcode, development-environment

I am new to Xcode. I use Eclipse however. Now I am creating my first project on Xcode but before I start, I like to setup a folder for all my Xcode projects.

I have three questions:

1. By default, when I create a new project (say Project1). Where is the root Project1 folder created?
2. Can I change that default location of where Project1 is created? So when I create Project2, it defaults to the same new modified location?
3. How can I delete project? Is deleting the root folder sufficient?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

I have just installed Xcode on a new MacBook and while testing I found out that ***when you create a new project the dialog will ask where to save the project***, then creates a folder in that directory. Next time it will automatically default to the same directory, but you can change directory anytime you wish.

Apologies for the previous answer inadvertence.

---

Original answer:

1. By default projects are saved in User/Documents/xCode
2. Not that I'm aware of. Every time you create a new project a correspondent folder is created.
3. Just delete the folder and its content.

Check out **Preferences** for all available settings. Pay special attention to "***Accounts***". Understanding now how Provisioning Profiles work may save some frustration later.

Additionally, consider using Pods for external libraries.